# user still signin with success after reinstall app with no internet

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I run below code, next press "Sign in" button with Google, choose account and user Signed in with SUCCESS. After that I uninstall this app, removed this application from Google Account Security Settings, synchronized google account on phone, then disabled Internet access in my phone, install this app again, again press button, choose account.... and still got message that this user signed in with success. For other accounts on this phone that I never use got message error 7 (no internet access). Why this user is still signed in?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val signInButton: SignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button)
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE)  //Optional

        var gso: GoogleSignInOptions =
            GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        signInButton.setOnClickListener {
            var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
            val signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 9001)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 9001) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            Log.d(
                "################# onActivityResult ################### ",
                account.email.toString()
            )
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in failed: " + e.getStatusCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It happens that way most likely because you haven't signed out the user, right?

Comment: Yes. Is there any option to remove all information without Sign Out? Or should I always execute Sing Out everytime I run application first time to clear data?

Comment: Yes, you should always sign out the user if you need to sign in again correctly.

Comment: Doesnt work, I added to onCreate:

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.delete()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.unlink("google.com")
and still when disconnect internet and reinstall app user can sign in.

Comment: Is the expected behavior to sign in. It's an authentication mechanism, right?